# Angular mouseleave not firing correctly while dragging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

In my angular project I using with drag and drop with library from [marceljuenemann](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists)

I try catch mouseleave event but it not firing because while dragging the mouse already clicked.

Thanks